# Geopandas: how to make spatial join between geoandas dataframes?

Tags: python, spatial, geopandas

I have two geopandas dataframes. One composed by polygon and another by points.

```
grid.head()

                                            geometry  zone
0   POLYGON ((-71.11007 42.36766, -71.10957 42.367...   0
1   POLYGON ((-71.11007 42.36716, -71.10957 42.367...   1
2   POLYGON ((-71.11007 42.36666, -71.10957 42.366...   2
3   POLYGON ((-71.11007 42.36616, -71.10957 42.366...   3
4   POLYGON ((-71.11007 42.36566, -71.10957 42.365...   4

gdf.head()
                     geometry
0   POINT (-71.09000 42.36000)
1   POINT (-71.09000 42.36000)
2   POINT (-71.09477 42.36407)
3   POINT (-71.09000 42.36000)
4   POINT (-71.09477 42.36407)
```

If I try to make a spatial join I get an error

```
from geopandas import sjoin
gdf = sjoin(grid, gdf)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

I tried to install `rtree`

```
sudo python3.7 -m pip install "rtree>=0.8,<0.9"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like at least one of the entries in the geometry column of either `grid` or `gdf` is `None`. `sjoin` needs to do spatial intersections on all the geometries, which it cannot do if they are `None`.

You can check if any of the following returns any rows:

```py
grid[grid.geometry.isnull()]
gdf[gdf.geometry.isnull()]
```