# Merging overlaying Dataframes by location (Pandas/GeoPandas)

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, qgis

Hi (this is my first post),

I have 2 Pandas Dataframes. The first one has roughly 80k Polygons with size 1km x 1km and the second has about 100k Polygons with 250mx250m. They are basically 2 maps of a country containing different information. All the smaller Polygons are inside a big one.
What I want to do is copy the Data from the Dataframe corresponding to a big Polygon onto the the Dataframes corresponding to the small Polygons that are inside.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

What I have tried so far is just a brute force approach using the "contains(.)" function from shapely. However running this nested loop would take about 2 days..

Thanks for any helpful comments!

```
        micro_df = pd.read_csv("Micro_250m_mit_Polygon_geometry.csv", sep=",",nrows=5000)

df = pd.read_csv("MergedWithFigures_Merged_ALL.csv", sep=",",nrows=5000)
df["geometry"] = df["geometry"].apply(wkt.loads)

gdf = geo.GeoDataFrame(df,crs="EPSG:4326")

micro_gdf = geo.GeoDataFrame(micro_df, geometry=geo.points_from_xy(micro_df.MP_X, micro_df.MP_Y),crs="EPSG:4326")
#micro_gdf = micro_gdf.to_crs("EPSG:31287")
print(micro_gdf.crs == gdf.crs)


Joined_gdf = geo.sjoin(micro_gdf, gdf)

gdf_big_v = (
    micro_gdf.sjoin(gdf, predicate="contains")
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(
        geometry=("geometry", "first"),
        #vals=("value", lambda s: ",".join(s.astype(str))),
        sum=("AverageDOWNLOAD"),
    )
    .pipe(lambda d: gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, geometry=d["geometry"], crs=micro_gdf.crs))
)
```

This is the current error message i get:

```
AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'sjoin'
```

This makes little sense to me since the Documentation of sjoin() states that it is used to merge 2 GeoDataframes...
I have also tried using

```
JOINED = geo.sjoin(micro_gdf,gdf,how="left")
```

This did merge the GeoDataframes, but the new entries from gdf where all set to NaN.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heXF0.png) of a small part of the map with the big squares in blue/green and the smaller squares in orange underneath.

To summarize, I want the Data from the column "AverageDOWNLOAD" in the big Polygon Dataframe to be copied into the small Polygon Dataframe if the small Polygon is inside the big one. (Here I used the center points of the small polygons but this should not make difference(?))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check out geopandas, and especially [`geopandas.sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html#geopandas-sjoin). This is a very large job and you may need to do this in batches, but I think sjoin may be up to the task. If not I’d recommend trying something like google BigQuery. It would be a whole different language but it’s lightning fast and very cheap for this type of operation.

Comment: What Josip is trying to highlight by pointing you to the [ask] guide is you’re more likely to get a helpful result (and avoid having your question closed) if you give us sufficient code and debugging detail to show us what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck. Ideally, give us a [mre] to work with so we can work through the problem with you. Good luck!

Comment: Check out this post for example (your solution is in the question): https://stackoverflow.com/q/61344111/3888719

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I have added some Code and tried to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have generated 9 polygons that *cover* 81 smaller polygons
- now `sjoin()` larger polygons to smaller polygons that have a measure *value*
- with this geometry a large polygon covers 9, smaller polygons. Hence need to aggregate results using **pandas** core functionality.  Have generated two aggregate reults.  1. comma separated values 2. sum of values
- have also demonstrated taking attribute from big polygons to small polygons
- finally to be able to understand this have provided a **folium** visualisation

```
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import folium

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

a, b, c, d = world.loc[world["name"].eq("Ukraine")].total_bounds.round(6)
g = 0
# generate some polygons that will cover other polygons
gdf_big = None
gdf_small = None
for i, dims in enumerate([(4, 4), (10, 10)]):
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        geometry=[
            shapely.geometry.box(minx + g, miny + g, maxx - g, maxy - g)
            for minx, maxx in zip(
                np.linspace(a, c, dims[0]), np.linspace(a, c, dims[0])[1:]
            )
            for miny, maxy in zip(
                np.linspace(b, d, dims[1]), np.linspace(b, d, dims[1])[1:]
            )
        ],
        crs="epsg:4326",
    )
    if i == 0:
        gdf_big = gdf
    else:
        gdf_small = gdf


# add some values to small and big polygons
gdf_small["value"] = gdf_small.index
gdf_big["big_value"] = gdf_big.centroid.x.astype(int).astype(str) + "_" + gdf_big.centroid.y.astype(int).astype(str)

# put big values against small polys
gdf_small = gdf_small.sjoin(gdf_big, predicate="within").drop(columns="index_right")

# sum values of small polygons covered by large polygons
# convert back to geodataframe
gdf_big_v = (
    gdf_big.sjoin(gdf_small, predicate="covers")
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(
        geometry=("geometry", "first"),
        vals=("value", lambda s: ",".join(s.astype(str))),
        sum=("value", "sum"),
    )
    .pipe(lambda d: gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, geometry=d["geometry"], crs=gdf_big.crs))
)

# visualise...
m = gdf_small.explore(name="small", color="yellow", height=300, width=500)
m = gdf_big_v.explore(m=m, name="big", color="blue")
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it was very helpful! I will try using sjoin() for my Problem.
The only problem ist that i want to copy the Data from the big layer onto the smaller one.
But I will try sjoin(.. , predicate = "contains") for that.

Comment: misread your q...  have updated to show taking value from big polygon to small polygons as well